# Response message: javax.mail.MessageRemovedException: can't retrieve message #1 in POP3Message.getContentStream

Tags: java, jmeter, smtp, imap, pop3

I am trying to implement mail protocol from the JMeter application. SMTP is working fine. In the case of POP3, I am getting the above error for some of the thread.

***Tried solutions:***

1. Certificated is assigned to the POP3
2. Increased the value of Authenticated time-out
3. Logon error is resolved

**Question: Why some of the threads are not getting the messages from the input stream during POP3 implementation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POP, as protocol, makes two big assumptions: First, nothing else modifies the mailbox while you're looking at it. Second, the messages are deleted or archived or something once you've looked (the server decides precisely what, the client can do opt out of that by taking some non-default action, I forget the details). This design shows up in every server and every client library. You're opening the mailbox in multiple threads, so you'll have problems with your server, your client library, or both.

You can try to use a single thread, you can change to IMAP, or you can try to investigate your client and server to steer clear of the problems you're seeing. All three are possible, even the third.

Comment: For a single thread, it is working fine. For more details, I am using MS-Exchange server 2016 as a mail server. But my question is- Can I access the mailbox for some of the threads using POP3 without any error? Or Do I need to change some settings in MS-Exchange Server?

Comment: You mean, can you access the same data structure from multiple threads without any locking? No you can't. Maybe you can activate some sort of locking in Exchange. If you do, it'll probably just lock out all except one thread.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you're using the same credentials (mailbox) with > 1 thread, this does not look like a normal use case to me so make sure to [parameterize your JMeter test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide) using i.e. [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to **ensure that different threads (virtual users) are using different credentials** and therefore accessing different mailboxes.

---

If your test assumes different logins already you can try to identify what's going on by enabling debug logging, in order to do this set `mail.debug` property to `true` either by adding the next line to *system.properties* file:

```
mail.debug=true
```

or by launching JMeter providing the aforementioned property via `-D` command-line argument

```
jmeter -Dmail.debug=true -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

More information:

- [JavaMail Frequently Asked Questions: Debugging](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug)
- [JMeter Properties Reference: Additional Property Files to Load](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#properties)
- [JMeter Getting Started: Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)